# Can I run a full bitcoin node on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: bitcoin-core, full-node, raspberry-pi

If so, what would be the best way to get started?

Comment: That's about 4 years old.. But I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I have one with an external usb hard drive if you want to store full blockchain or without it if you run a pruned node.

Comment: Thanks could you point me in the direction to where I can get started?

Comment: If you want full Bitcoin node and Lightning you have a script here: https://github.com/jochemin/raspnode